# Japanese monster movie from late 70's early 80's

Tags: story-identification, movie

I've been trying to remember these films from back when I was a kid

A kid would draw a monster on a wall or concrete pipe. Later that night lighting hits it and it comes alive. The army fights it or something like that. I'm 47 now, so this would probably be in the 70s or 80s.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an original Ultraman TV episode "Terrifying Cosmic Rays".   Where a cosmic ray turns a child's chalk drawing into a kaiju.

http://ultra.wikia.com/wiki/Terrifying_Cosmic_Rays

monster is Gavadon.

http://ultra.wikia.com/wiki/Gavadon

Comment: OMG.. Yes that was it thanks so very much!! Your the best!!

Comment: my pleasure!  I loved Ultraman when he first came to the states